# How to properly prepare artwork in Illustrator 2020 to save as an EPS

Tags: eps

I am not an expert, obviously, but I am learning. I have created a design and when I try to save it as an EPS file, I am getting alot of extra noise in one particular area.  The area is where I created military dog tags with multiple effects.  I have tried rasterizing, flattening, etc. but am still getting a very thin square outline around the objects. What am I doing wrong please?  And thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You are not going to magic it away with settings. Most likely the thin square is a conflation artefact. Its a bug in the rendering engine. Simply put things have to overlap for screen presentation purposes, this ought not happen in print unless you have a really really bad RIP engine. But why would you use EPS?

Comment: Check the Document Raster Effects setting, make sure it’s at least 300 dpi. Unless you’re having problems with the transparency printing, I wouldn’t flatten your art, you remove most of the ability to make any changes. Next, sometimes flattened transparencies get a white hairline on screen, but print fine. And finally, check your overlapping shapes, you might have a white box under an object and if it’s too close to the edge it may show when rasterized. If you could show us pictures of what’s happening & tell us what you are trying to use this for, we could help you more.

Comment: .. gotta kind of *see* the problem to diagnose it...

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I was having issues with the transparency and not sure what the issue was.  I was able to go back to a previous version and save the file with transparency.  I'm glad I saved a new file with each step.  Thanks again!